# How to add local image to flutter_local_notifications

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

I am trying to create push notifications and would like to add an image to the notification. I am able to add images from the web as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

How can I add a local image instead? I tried adding the file path as shown below, but it did not work:

[image]

Comment: how to add image for andriod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file path you are adding is a root path of your project but this method needs an android file path(e.g. `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.expampe.app/cache/bg.png`), so you have to convert your asset image to a File and save it, then return its path:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<String> getImageFilePathFromAssets(String asset) async {
  final byteData = await rootBundle.load(asset);

  final file =
      File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/${asset.split('/').last}');
  await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer
      .asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));

  return file.path;
}
```

then just

```
final attachmentPicturePath = await getImageFilePathFromAssets('assets/image2.jpg');
```

Comment: Do you have any ideas how I could the same thing on the android side?

Comment: @marcorivera8 please update question with your android code

Answer (score 1):

The Easiest Way is--

```
static Future<String> getImageFilePathFromAssets(
   String asset, String filename) async {
   final byteData = await rootBundle.load(asset);
   final temp_direactory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
   final file = File('${temp_direactory.path}/$filename');
   await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, 
   byteData.lengthInBytes));

return file.path;
```

}

```
final bigpicture = await Utils.getImageFilePathFromAssets(
    'assets/images/largicon.png', 'bigpicture');
```

And For donwload Using URL---
add http and path_provider in pubspec.yml

```
  static Future<String> downloadFile(String URL, String filename) async 
   {
     final direactory = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
     final filepath = '${direactory.path}/$filename';
     final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(URL));
     print(response);

     final file = File(filepath);

    await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
return filepath;
```

}

[check this demo github](https://github.com/sunil-singh-chaudhary/Custom-Notification)